# Polyline Stroke Color with Alpha doesn't work in Here API v3.1

Tags: here-api

I am migrating from the v3.0 of the Here Javascript API to v3.1, and it seems that the latest version doesn't support alpha values for the strokeColor of Polylines.  If your use an 8 digit hex code (the last two digits being alpha), the line is displayed as White.  This worked fine in version 3.0 and is handy when displaying overlapping routes.

Here's an example JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/phil_sweeney/mk2z761j/

```
  // '4d' = 30% alpha
  map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
    lineString, { style: {strokeColor:'#f7a36f4d', lineWidth: 4 }}
  ));
```

strokeColor is set to: '#f7a36f4d'.  If you remove the '4d' from the end (30% alpha), you'll get an orange-ish line.

Is this considered a bug which is going to be fixed - or is this just the way it's going to be from here out?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We are looking into it and will let you when a fix is available. For now please use the `rgba` syntax as suggested by @Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue on WEBGL rendering engine.

For now I suggest using `rgba` instead of hexadecimal color:

```
map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
  lineString, { style: {strokeColor:'rgba(247, 163, 111, 0.3)', lineWidth: 4 }}
));
```